# Magento 2: Round Cents in 2 digit format

Tags: magento2, price

I have some products with 2 decimals, as eg: 28.88, I would like to round the last decimal so the product price would be 28.89.

Also if the price is 28.84, round them to 28.80.
Which means if price last digit is >5 then round up, ad if last digit is <5,then round down.

Thanks for your help, I've followed some tutorials but I only make the price to be cutted off into a 1 decimal.

Answer (score 0):

There is a free plugin which you can install and use it. This will round off prices on listing, production, cart view and checkout summary page.

https://github.com/lillik/magento2-price-decimal

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. Unfortunately, this just cut off the decimal from the price, this can be done chaning the deep of decimal in magento core. What I need is to round up like this: 45.99 = 46.00 keeping the same decimal.